# MySQL & Memcached - Simple retrieve query not working

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

Basicaly is my first time using memcached... I am trying to run a simple query and for some reason is not working... the tutorials about memcached are not great and i have no idea why is not working my query

```
    <?php

    //connect to memcached server and MySQL
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'admin', '');
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect"); 


 // Run the query and get the data from the database then cache it
 $category_querry = $db->query('SELECT * FROM category WHERE category_id=1');
 $category_querry->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $category_querry->fetch()) {

 $memcache->set(1, $row['category_name'], 30); // Store the result of the query for 20 seconds
  var_dump($memcache->get(1));
 echo "</br> Data Pulled from the Database </br>";
}


$get_result = $memcache->get(1);
var_dump($get_result);

if ($get_result) 
    {
echo "</br>" . $get_result['category_name'];
echo "</br>" .  "Data Pulled From Cache";
}
```

**Code Updated** Now somehow i made it enter the IF statement and what shows in the browser is

```
string(3) "one" 
Data Pulled from the Database 
string(3) "one" 
o
Data Pulled From Cache
```

this then shows me that all the var_dumps work.... and it gets to the if statement but somehow the `$get_result['category_name']` is only outputting `o` when it should be outputting `one`

why???

Answer (score 0):

While setting memcache you don't have $key variable defined

```
$memcache->set($key, $row, TRUE, 60);
```

You need to define $key before setting it in memcache

Comment: I added  `$key = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE category_id=1";` before the while loop. Still not entering the IF statement below... the funny thing is that when i do `var_dump($row)` in the while statement it return and error

Comment: Undefined variable: var_dump in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\interview\1.php on line 16

Comment: "$var_dump ($memcache->set($key));"  should be "var_dump($memcache->set($key));" Omit the preceding $; but that's not the problem...

Comment: thx robbie... now i somehow mannaged get into the if tatement and get the value... but now is not outputting the right thing